# Laravel Validator::extendedDependent() dynamic error message

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

```
Validator::extendDependent('cbu_deposit', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator){     
             $arr = explode('.', $attribute);
             $account = $validator->getData()[$arr[0]][$arr[1]];

             $type = $account['type'];
             if($value < $type['minimum_deposit_per_transaction']){
                return false;
             }
             return true;
});
```

According to the **laravel api** the third parameter is the $message

```
void extendDependent(string $rule, Closure|string $extension, string|null $message = null)
```

I'm wondering how to make he error message dynamic like this

```
$error = "Mininum deposit for " .$type['product_id']. ' is : '.$type['minimum_deposit_per_transaction'].'.';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer using the `$validator->addReplacer()` method inside `Validator::extendDependent('cbu_deposit')`.

```
 $customMessage = "Mininum deposit for " .$type['product_id']. ' is : '.$type['minimum_deposit_per_transaction'].'.';

            $validator->addReplacer('cbu_deposit', 
                function($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) use ($customMessage) {
                    return \str_replace(':custom_message', $customMessage, $message);
                }
            );
```

Answer (score 3):

you can add variables to error messages like this:

```
Mininum deposit for :id is : :deposit.
```

check 
https://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-error-messages